# Magento frontend and backend broke : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, base-url, localhost, core-config-data

```
/app/etc/env.php --- 'localhost' vs '127.0.0.1'
```

I changed ***localhost  to  127.0.0.1*** however my Magento frontend and backend broke after that.

```
    'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'shop',
            'username' => 'shop',
            'password' => '1234567',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
],
```

came to know from server that somehow mysql crashed, and they had to work on mysql conf files to recover. 
i am still unable to understand what went wrong??

Answer (score 1):

***http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php***

*Open* ***core_config_data*** *table in database*

```
web/unsecure/base_url => http://127.0.0.1/magento232/
web/secure/base_url = > https://127.0.0.1/magento232/
```

see attched image

[image]

***Then run command in terminal/putty***

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: my core_config_data says - web/unsecure/base_url - http://www.luxeron.in/pro and web/secure/base_url - https://luxeron.in/pro,

Comment: @NittnWarshne okay, frontend is working fine. what's the problem?

Comment: thanks @savanpatel, however  --- nittn.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed., and my web server support helped "We rectified the issue by adding 'innodb_force_recovery = 1' in /usr/local/apps/mysql56/etc/my.cnf file located on your server. Once added, we restarted MySQL service and now MySQL is working fine." why the website broke is still a mystery??

Comment: reference link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Comment: thanks @savanpatel